# Why does it print random symbols when exceeding 44 characters

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C from a book C programming:Modern approach. Right now I'm going trough exercises about arrays. One of the exercises is to write a filter that prints the input message differently.

I've gotten so far (see the code below), everything works fine, until the character count exceeds 44, then it prints random symbols. If the character count is below 44 everything works fine. I have absolutely no clue why it does that. Where is the problem and what might be the solution?

```
int i = 0, k = 0;
char message[k],ch;

printf("Enter a message: ");
while(toupper(ch = getchar()) != '\n')
{
    message[k] = ch;
    k++;
}
printf("In B1FF-speak: ");
for (i = 0; i <= k - 1; i++)
{
    switch(toupper(message[i]))
    {
        case 'A':
            printf("4");
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("8");
            break;
        case 'E':
            printf("3");
            break;
        case 'I':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case 'O':
            printf("0");
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf("5");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c", toupper(message[i]));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char message[k]` with `k` set to 0? Is that a serious question???

Comment: @lurker: `char message[k]` where `k==0` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @barakmanos: The OP has apparently assumed that changing the value of `k` changes the length of the array. It's not  an entirely unreasonable assumption; it just happens to be incorrect.

Comment: @KeithThompson OK, got it. But a bad idea in either case.

Comment: @lurker: What's a bad idea? It would be a great idea if it worked.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yep, I see that now. Sometimes understanding the subject's way of thinking in order to explain what's wrong with it, is a challenging task by itself (one that you seemed to have dealt with quite well). I guess that too many years of programming have made my ability to see "beyond the boundaries" into other perceptions (a natural perception in this specific case, if I may add, now that I see your point) -  a little blunt. **P.S.: it's funny how the obvious things sometimes elude you**.

Comment: Let me tell you why I placed K there at the first place, when I put an array value, for example 50, if I enter only 40 characters, the rest of them will be 10 random chars. Maybe someone can tell me how to fix that. As I said I'm new, I was just experimenting what might work.

Comment: If you have a 50-element array and you assign to the first 40 elements, then yes, the last 10 elements will have arbitrary (not truly "random") values. Is that a problem? Just keep track of which elements you've set, and don't use the rest. There's usually no reason to care what values they have. If you want the array to contain a *string*, store `'\0'` after the last element; for example a `char[]` array starting with `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'` can be treated as a string of length 5.

Comment: I have no Idea what a string is (haven't gotten that far), and yes, that is the problem, that it has arbitrary values. I use the first 40 elements. The rest of the 10 stay empty, so it shows those arbitrary symbols. Any idea how to fix it? The one answer below shows me a function that I see for the first time, there must be something else that I can do.

Comment: @TacoCat a string? In C that is an informal term for a particular usage of a `char[]` array which has a 0 value end marker, used to store text such as "Hello world!" There are many functions in the library accessed by `#include <string.h>` such as finding its length with `strlen()` and copying it with `strcpy()` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's not informal at all. The ISO C standard defines a "string" as "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".

Comment: If you only need the first 40 elements, the fact that there's arbitrary data in the last 10 *doesn't matter*. Just don't use those elements unless you've assigned a value to them. If you store a *string* in the array, the last used element is marked by the terminating `'\0'` character; otherwise, you need to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @KeithThompson thank you. I was sure I had read comments to the effect that C does not have a string type.

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's correct, C doesn't have a string *type*. A C "string" is a data format, not a data type.

Comment: @KeithThompson if you look at the code in the FOR loop, right now the value is K, but if I make the array message[50]; I have to put 50 in the FOR loop as well, so it uses the 10 values that I don't need, this is where the arbitrary symbols come from. I have no idea how to fix it. :( 
I tried putting '\0' at the end but that didn't help as well. *Maybe I used it wrong, this is the first time I encounter something like this*

Comment: No, you don't *have* to use 50 in the `for` loop. For example, you can define your array with 50 elements, then loop over the first **N** elements.

Comment: How would that look in code? the define part i know, but looping over the first N elements is unclear to me.

Answer (score 9):

```
int i = 0, k = 0;
char message[k],ch;
```

You've defined `message` as a *variable length array* (VLA). (This is a feature that doesn't exist in the 1990 version of C; it was added by the 1999 standard and made optional by the 2011 standard.)

Since the value of `k` is `0`, the length of `message` is `0`. C does not support zero-length arrays. Defining an array with a constant length of zero is illegal (a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic). Defining a variable length array with a length of zero has undefined behavior.

The length of a VLA is fixed when it's defined. Changing the value of `k` later on does not change the length of the array. Your code seems to assume that it will.

Your program *seems* to work for lengths up to 44.  That's the nature of undefined behavior. The *worst* thing that can happen is that your program seems to work "correctly"; that just means that you have a bug that's difficult to detect.

If you want to store arbitrarily many elements in an array, you can either define it with a size that's big enough in the first place (it can be difficult or impossible to determine how big it has to be), or you can use `realloc()` to allocate the array dynamically and expand it as needed. (`realloc()` doesn't actually expand the array; it creates a new array with a larger size and copies the contents of the old array into the new array. And it can fail if there isn't enough available memory; always check the value it returns to determine whether it succeeded or failed.)